# What annotation am I missing in my project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

I've read the similar questions but couldn't find the solution.

I'm using Vaadin and Spring Boot. I have a previous project which is running well without getting this White Label message and I'm using the same annotations and everything. In the entry point Spring Boot class I defined @SpringBootApplication.

"This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Dec 28 18:56:32 CET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available"

In the same time I think the problem comes from my POM.

Thank you for the help to not committing the same problem next time.

My Service class:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate JdbcTemplate;

    public List<Person>

            findAll() {
                return JdbcTemplate.query(
                        "SELECT Név, Mérkőzések_száma, Győzelmek_száma, Vereségek_száma FROM Darts",
                        (rs, rowNum) -> new Person(rs.getString("nev"), 
                        rs.getInt("games"), rs.getInt("wins"), rs.getInt("loses")));
            }
            public void update(Person person) {
                JdbcTemplate.update(
                        "UPDATE Darts SET Mérkőzések_száma=?, Győzelmek_száma=?, Vereségek_száma=? WHERE Név=?)",
                        person.getGames(), person.getWins(), person.getLoses(), person.getName());
            }

}
```

My Person class:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int games;
    private int wins;
    private int loses;

    public Person(String name, int games, int wins, int loses) {
        this.name = name;
        this.games = games;
        this.wins = wins;
        this.loses = loses;
    }

    public int getLoses() {
        return loses;
    }

    public void setLoses(int loses) {
        this.loses = loses;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getGames() {
        return games;
    }

    public void setGames(int games) {
        this.games = games;
    }

    public int getWins() {
        return wins;
    }

    public void setWins(int wins) {
        this.wins = wins;
    }



}
```

My MainView class:

```
import com.vaadin.data.Binder;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;
import com.vaadin.spring.annotation.SpringUI;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@SpringUI
public class MainView extends UI {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService service;

    private TextField name = new TextField("Name");
    private TextField games = new TextField("Game");
    private TextField wins = new TextField("Win");
    private TextField loses = new TextField("Lose");

    private Person person;

    private final Binder<Person> bind = new Binder<>(Person.class);
    private final Grid<Person> grid = new Grid<>(Person.class);



    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {

        grid.setColumns("name", "games", "wins", "loses");

        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout(grid, name, games, wins, loses);

        setContent(layout);


}
}
```

POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.benjaminhalasz</groupId>
    <artifactId>darts</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>darts</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.1.3</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-spring</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Edited:
application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/vizsgadb_HB
spring.datasource.username=vizsgauser_HB
spring.datasource.password=12345678
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it seems that :

- In your POM, you should remove the dependency `vaadin-spring`. It is a different version that the one that is imported by `vaadin-spring-boot-starter`. When using a starter, try using only the starter, nothing else. They are made to carry every dependencies you need.
- You should replace @SpringUI with @Route. For more information, check this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-vaadin

Let me know if any of this worked.

Comment: It's working now after I removed the dependency vaadin-spring as you suggested. And I had to do other changes in the POM so I could keep the same template as I posted above. The POM was the source of the problem but I don't know how since I downloaded a starter kit only what I needed for with the newest version of Vaadin, MySQL and JDBC. But the point is that it's running well.